# Портирование библиотеки

Tags: c, borland

Я использую Open Watcom копилятор для сборки DOS 16 приложения под 80188 подобную архитектуру. Проблема заключается в том, что я не могу подключить библиотеку собранную в BC 3.1. После, казалось бы, успешной линковки, при использовании некоторых функций из этой библиотеки, я получаю сообщения от линковщика, что не найден символ `_malloc()` или `_free()`. Использование функции `malloc()` в пользовательском коде проходит линковку.

Как я понял проблема возникает только, когда какя либо функция библиотеки вызывает `malloc()` или `free()`, то есть библиотека нифига не стэндалон и тянет зависимости из стандартной бибилотеки собранной для BC 3.1. Проверить это я никак не могу и пересобрать библиотеку тоже, так как ее исходников нет.

Всвязи с этим у меня вопрос: как портировать билиотеку на Open Watcom ? `malloc()` и `free()` есть в библиотеках Open Watcom но их символы скомпилированы видимо не так как того ожидает борландовская библиотека.

Answer (score 3):

Ну да, похоже что библиотека BC из себя обращается к malloc() и free(), ожидая при этом имена в формате с подчёркиванием в начале. А в библиотеках Watcom эти функции могут быть без подчёркивания, или вообще с подчёркиванием в конце... Проверить это можно просто посмотрев дамп имён ваткомовской библиотеки (clib кажись). wlib из их стандартной поставки должен это уметь, а может и wlink... Если там не обнаружится имён _malloc и _free, то самый простой выход - сделать свои обёртки:

```
void * _malloc( size_t sz ) { return malloc(sz); };
void _free( void * mem ) { free(mem); };
```

И линковать их с проектом.

UPD: Таки проверил. Действительно, Open Watcom 1.8.0, clib3r.lib (register calling):

```
free_   .... nfree.c
malloc_ .... nmalloc.c
```

И для clib3s.lib  (stack calling, чего борланд и ожидает):

```
free   .... nfree.c
malloc .... nmalloc.c
```

Так что - обёртка.

Comment: И при этом дамп main.o показывает, что имена _malloc и _free в нём есть?

Comment: dmpobj показывает что нет там _malloc(), если я все правильно понял =)

Comment: Выяснил в чем проблема с объектными файлами. Если использовать обертку _malloc(), то в объектном файле появиться символ __malloc(), если оставить все, как есть то будет malloc_(). Так как сделать что бы был просто _malloc()? Писать __cdecl нельзя.

Comment: Думаю, в первую очередь надо поковыряться с ключами компилятора. Подчёркивание в конце добавляется при регистровой передаче аргументов, а это уж явно не то, что ожидает борландовская библиотека в любом случае.

P.S. Но пишу всё это по памяти, ибо 16-битный Watcom и Windows/DOS живьём в руках не держал давно :) Во всяком про подчёркивание в конце гарантировано могу подтвердить на 32-разрядном ваткоме про Debian, и под DOS было так же вроде.

Comment: Eсли все подключить в лоб, то тупо не компилится ибо либа использует cdecl, а компилятор нет. Компилятору передается ключ -ecc который заставляет его использовать cdecl везде где только можно. Все компилируется все работает, НО по той поры пока пользователь не вызовет НЕКОТОРЫЕ функции из этой библиотеки. Т.е. функции библиотеки видимо как то используют malloc() из стандартной билиотеки, но той что шла с борландом. И не понятно как заставить их вызывать malloc_(), а не _malloc(). . Мб можно как то модифицировать lib файл, что бы изменить описание сивола, которая она использует ?

Comment: Тогда я бы поставил в отладчике брекпойнты на вызовах этих самых функций и посмотрел бы что именно и как там вызывается, и на чём вылетает. Раз линкер собирает, то не исключено что проблема в способе вызова функций.
И потом, что мешает собрать из двух этих обёрток отдельную либу, в которой они будут явно cdecl? Остального кода это же не коснётся.

Comment: Не сборка проходит только, когда проблемных функций из библотеки никто не вызывает.

Comment: Значит, нужно добиваться о ваткома создания cdecl версий _malloс и _free. В чём тут может быть проблема - непонятно.